# Can't move my widget position which writed in .py file

Tags: python, widget, kivy

Hello and thanks for reading. I have trouble about move widget position on screen. Actually i checked widget's position, its changing as i want but at the screen i can't see any changing. I tried this too, in for loop `self.remove_widget(i)` and then `self.add_widget(i)`. But there is nothing changed too.

**.py file :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color,Rectangle
from random import randint

class Page(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.list1 = []
        self.list2 = []
        self.currentball = 0

    def add(self):
        self.currentball += 1
        self.list1.append('Ball[{}]'.format(self.currentball))
        self.list2.append(self.list1[len(self.list1)-1])
        print('List1 => ',self.list1)
        print('List2 => ',self.list2)
        #Widget oluşturalım:
        self.list2[len(self.list1)-1] = Widget(size_hint=(.1,.1),pos=(randint(100,200),randint(250,500)))
        with self.list2[len(self.list1)-1].canvas:
            Color(1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle(source='worker.png',size=self.list2[len(self.list1)-1].size,pos=self.list2[len(self.list1)-1].pos)
        self.add_widget(self.list2[len(self.list1)-1])

    def move(self):
        for i in self.list2:
            i.pos[0] += randint(0,20)
            print(i.pos)

    def remove(self):
        self.update()


class ScMn(ScreenManager):
    pass

class test2(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScMn()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test2().run()
```

**.kv file :**

```
<ScMn>:
    Page:
        name: 'page'
        id: pageid

<Page>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: .1,.1
            pos: 0,0
            text: 'Add'
            on_press: root.add()
        Button:
            size_hint: .1,.1
            pos_hint:{'x':.1,'y':0}
            text: 'Move'
            on_press: root.move()
        Button:
            size_hint: .1,.1
            pos_hint:{'x':.2,'y':0}
            text: 'RemoveLast'
            on_press: root.remove()
```

Thanks for answering already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Implement a custom widget class, e.g. `MyWidget()` with method to update `pos` and `size`
2. Replace `Widget(...)` with `MyWidget(...)`
3. Remove `with self.list2[len(self.list1)-1].canvas: ...` because it is done in the new class `MyWidget()`

### Snippets

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size


class Page(Screen):

    ...
    def add(self):
        ...
        self.list2[len(self.list1) - 1] = MyWidget(size_hint=(.1, .1), pos=(randint(100, 200), randint(250, 500)))
        self.add_widget(self.list2[len(self.list1) - 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.Its working.. Can i ask why ,  when i create any widget in .kv file and change thats pos , its moving but when i create in .py file why it doesn't move ? What is differences between kv & py effects ?

Comment: In kv file, it automatically generated the binding whereas in py file, you have to provide the binding.